# Error name collision detected

Tags: react-native

I am getting this error while running "react-native start".

```
[1:00:56 AM] <END>   Building (deprecated) Asset Map (504ms)
Failed to build DependencyGraph: Naming collision detected: C:\La
testSMFApp\TestApp\node_modules\react-native-list-popover\node_modules\react-
native\Libraries\ART\ARTSerializablePath.js collides with C:\Late
stSMFApp\TestApp\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ART\ARTSerializablePath.
js
Error: Naming collision detected: C:\MyApp\TestApp\node
_modules\react-native-list-popover\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ART\ARTSe
rializablePath.js collides with C:\MyApp\TestApp\node_m
odules\react-native\Libraries\ART\ARTSerializablePath.js
    at HasteMap._updateHasteMap (HasteMap.js:132:13)
    at HasteMap.js:103:28
    at tryCallOne (C:\MyApp\TestApp\node_modules\promis
e\lib\core.js:37:12)
    at C:\MyApp\TestApp\node_modules\promise\lib\core.j
s:123:15
    at flush (C:\MyApp\TestApp\node_modules\asap\raw.js
:50:29)
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:452:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:381:13)
```

I have tried clearning my node_modules folder and recreating it. How can I resolve this?

Node version : 5.5.0
react-native version : 0.21.0(Tried with 0.20.0 also, not working)

Answer (score 2):

As the error says there is a collision in your node module. Popover module itself include react native. If you remove react native folder under popover, then it will work.

Comment: Thanks. Now it is working. Can I add something in package.json to not download react native while downloading popover module?

Comment: Using blacklist may solve your problem. Have a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34805283/1134897 . Please let me know if its works.