# Blacklisting Module in react native takes no effect

Tags: node.js, react-native, node-modules

according to a previously asked question [How to blacklist specific node_modules of my package's dependencies in react-native's packager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049111/how-to-blacklist-specific-node-modules-of-my-packages-dependencies-in-react-nat)

I created such a file in my project root directory. Name: rn-cli.config.js

My file content:

```
var blacklist = require('react-native/packager/blacklist');

var config = {
  getBlacklistRE(platform) {
    return blacklist(platform, [
      /node_modules\/react\/lib\/TouchHistoryMath.js/
    ]);
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

I am trying to target the Module directly since it's the only one causing an error where two modules have the same name.

Now when I try to re-run my project (start with xCode) i still get the same duplicate error for the same module.

Do I need to do something else than just simply creating that file?

Comment: A bit late, but in case others stumble on this; the `platform` parameter is no longer used. Removing it from the call to the `blacklist` fn should fix it.

Comment: Any update here, I removed platform but it still doesnt works

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41813211/how-to-make-react-native-packager-ignore-certain-directories/41963217#41963217

Comment: @Arun Already tried that. Its not working. Seems like whatever regex I am providing, it gets silently ignored. I am working with latest version of react-native.

Comment: @sunny I don't remember the solution that I had and if I had any. It was a testproject 2 years ago. Hope you will find something

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using something like this:

```
    const modulePaths = require('./modulePaths');
    const resolve = require('path').resolve;
    const fs = require('fs');

    const config = {
    getTransformOptions: () => {
        const moduleMap = {};
        modulePaths.forEach(path => {
        if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
            moduleMap[resolve(path)] = true;
        }
        });
        return {
        preloadedModules: moduleMap,
        transform: { inlineRequires: { blacklist: moduleMap } },
        };
    },
    };

    module.exports = config;
```

Here's a link to [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#updating-the-configjs).

Comment: how to get modulePaths. I have follow the same steps which is mention on document, but in doc not mention the this file.https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance#updating-the-configjs