# How do I keep the packager from trying to include a file that doesn't exist?

Tags: socket.io, react-native

I am trying to use `socket.io-client` in my React app and am running into an odd problem. Deep inside `engine.io` (required by `socket.io-client`) there is a file called websocket.js with the following bit of code:

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  try {
    NodeWebSocket = require('ws');
  } catch (e) { }
}
```

Since `window` is not undefined, you might think that this code does nothing, but you’d be wrong.

My packager (the standard React Native packager, so far as I know) goes through all the Javascript files and looks for all the `import` and `require` commands, and packages up the files they refer to.

The `ws` module contains a file called `WebSocket.js`, which intended for Node.js and makes use of Node.js modules like `url.js` and `http.js`, which of course do not exist in React, so the attempt at packaging fails.

Deleting those five lines fixed the problem and everything worked, but there must be a better way.  Can I tell the packager to exclude certain modules?

Comment: FYI there is an open issue at React Native Product Pains on this: https://productpains.com/post/react-native/packager-support-resolvealias-ala-webpack/ - and there doesn't seem to be a great workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to reproduce your problem, but you can try to blacklist the `ws` package.

[How to blacklist specific node_modules of my package's dependencies in react-native's packager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30049111/how-to-blacklist-specific-node-modules-of-my-packages-dependencies-in-react-nat)

Comment: I found out the reason you couldn't repro.  I was using a slightly older version of the React packager, which did not understand `false` as a value in the `browser` object of package.json.

Answer (score 0):

**You can try the below code :**

```
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
      try {
        var wsNode = 'ws' // store node module name in a string
        NodeWebSocket = require(wsNode); // dynamic require will exclude the node module to get bundled in react-native
      } catch (e) { }
    }
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did do, but going into production would require forking the engine-io package and the socket-io package.  I was looking for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't solve my problem as posed, but I figured out what was going on, why I was having difficulties other users were not.

In the file `node_modules/engine.io-client/package.json` was the following entry:

```
  "browser": {
    "ws": false,
    "xmlhttprequest-ssl": "./lib/xmlhttprequest.js"
  },
```

My venerable version of the React packager did not understand the "false" to mean "skip including ws [WebSockets] when you are building for the client side".  Upgrading the packager made the problem go away.